# Concat Strings to numbers using Recursive

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

### XML coding is given below

```
<math>
  <mn>
    <mphantom>12</mphantom>
  </mn>
</math>
```

### Output required:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<math>|phantom1||phantom2|</math>
```

### XSLT tried:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:cl="http://xml.cengage-learning.com/cendoc-core"
  xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mn">
        <xsl:variable name="pText" select="." />
        <xsl:variable name="numst" select="2" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(string-length($pText))&gt;0">
                <xsl:value-of select="$pText" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="ConcatStr" select="substring($pText,$numst)" />
                <xsl:variable name="FinalStr" select="substring-before($pText,$ConcatStr)" />
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">|phantom</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$FinalStr" />
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">|</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mphantom">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I used the above XSLT to transform but I am getting only the first number. But I need to use it as recursive. I am using XSLT 1.0. Kindly suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is a simpler, *non-recursive* solution, using the [Piez method](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/muench.html#d9945e300)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="mphantom">
     <math>
     <xsl:variable name="vCur" select="."/>
      <xsl:for-each select=
       "(document('')//node()|document('')//@*|document('')//namespace::*)
          [not(position() > string-length($vCur))]
       ">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('|', substring($vCur, position(), 1),'|')"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
     </math>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<math>
    <mn>
        <mphantom>12</mphantom>
    </mn>
</math>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<math>|1||2|</math>
```

---

**II. For completeness, here is an XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="mphantom">
     <math>
       <xsl:value-of separator="" select=
        "for $i in 1 to string-length()
          return
             concat('|', substring(., $i, 1), '|')
        "/>
     </math>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mn[mphantom]" name="phant">
  <xsl:param name="chars" select="mphantom" />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('|phantom',substring($chars,1,1),'|')" />
  <xsl:if test="substring($chars,2)">
    <xsl:call-template name="phant">
      <xsl:with-param name="chars" select="substring($chars,2)" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```