# xml file parsing with xmlint and carriage return

Tags: xml-parsing

I am using xmlint to parse a xml document.

sample document is this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<top>
<c>
    <a n="zzz"><i>0</i></a>
</c>
<c>
    <a n="zzz"><i>1</i></a>
</c>
</top>
```

I am doing something like this

```
xmllint -xpath '//top/c/a[@n="zzz"]/i/text()' a.xml
```

and I get

```
<i>0</i><i>165</i>
```

If I do

```
xmllint -xpath '/ad/c/a[@n="sid"]/i/text()' f.xml
```

I get 
01

My desired output is (there is a carriage return)

0

1

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update your question by including a minimal sample XML document.  See this guide for more info - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select an xml element, ignore element name, print newline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053097/select-an-xml-element-ignore-element-name-print-newline)